# Revalidate next 11 On-Demand ISR

Tags: node.js

Please tell me how I can force through the api * to update the cache* of the page I need, or how can I not achieve such an opportunity in the current version?

```
//pages/api/revalidate.js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
await res.revalidate('/[news]')//примерный вариант развития событий
}
```